# JSF/Seam -- Nested/Recursive iteration

Tags: jsf, seam, facelets

I've got a situation where I would like to perform nested iterations on a series of options and display the results using JSF.  As an example, think of a discussion board.  Each comment may contain a parent comment and 0-n child comments.  So, my root object would be something like this:

```
public class MyObject {

...

public List<Comment> getComments();

...
}
```

And my comments would look like this:

```
public class Comment {

...

public Comment getParent();

...

public List<Comment> getChildComments();

...
}
```

I've got all of my entities setup using JPA and they are populated within the database.  But, my dilema is, how do I iterate over each comment so I can display its child comments inline?  I know I can use `<ui:repeat value="#{myObj}" var="comment" />` to iterate over the root-level comments for an object.  But, how do I then iterate over the children comments for each of those?  And then, how do I iterate over *their* child comments.  And so on, and so on.

Has anyone ever done anything like this?  I suppose "Nested Iteration" could really be thought of more as "recursive iteration".  Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

For fixed-size nested iterations, simply use:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{myObj}" var="comment">
    <ui:repeat value="#{comment}" var="subComment">
        <ui:repeat value="#{subComment}" var="subSubComment">
        </ui:repeat>
    </ui:repeat>
</ui:repeat>
```

If you want full recursion, fetch the data in some Tree structure in your bean, using whatever loops you like, and use it just for visualization, in a simple iteration. You may need to have a "level" property of the objects that you put in your Tree.